# How to invalidate a SQL statement in the Oracle SQL area so that a new plan is produced when collecting statistics

Tags: oracle, statistics

I have a table and a query (within a PL/SQL packge) accessing that table.  Statistics are collected weekly normally.

A large update has been run on the table, resulting in significantly different data distribution on a particular indexed column.  The query plan used by Oracle (which I can see from `v$sqlarea`) is sub-optimal.  If I take an `explain plan` on the same* query from SQL*Plus, a good plan is returned.

I have since collected statistics on the table.  Oracle is still using the query plan that it originally came up with.  `v$sqlarea.last_load_time` suggests this was a plan generated prior to the statistics generation.  I thought regenerating statistics would have invalidated plans in the SQL cache.

Is there any way to remove just this statement from the SQL cache?

(* Not character-for-character, matches-in-the-SQL-cache same, but the same statement).

Comment: Why not just use `alter system flush shared_pool` and get rid of all plans?

Comment: Could flush everything, but it would get rid of all plans, packages etc. which would have a detrimental effect on other (more important) things.  The thing that is running slowly has gone from 6 seconds to a couple of minutes but it runs in the background.

Comment: @ammoQ - Flushing the entire shared pool is massive overkill here.  You'd force Oracle to re-parse all the SQL statements that are currently cached.  That could introduce some substantial performance problems if you did it on a production system.

Comment: Justin Cave: If you do it just once, people probably won't even notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out (when researching something else) that what I should have done was to use

```
no_invalidate => FALSE
```

When collecting the statistics by calling `gather_table_stats`.  This would have caused all SQL plans referencing the table to immediately be invalidated.

The [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm) say:

```
Does not invalidate the dependent cursors if set to TRUE. The procedure 
invalidates the dependent cursors immediately if set to FALSE. Use
DBMS_STATS.AUTO_INVALIDATE. to have Oracle decide when to invalidate dependent
cursors. This is the default.
```

The default of `AUTO_INVALIDATE` seems to cause invalidation of SQL statements within the next 5 hours.  This is to stop massive number of hard-parses if you are collecting statistics on lots of objects.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using 10.2.0.4 or later, you should be able to use the DBMS_SHARED_POOL package to [purge a single cursor from the shared pool](http://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/stuck-execution-plans-purging-a-cursor/).

Comment: Thankyou for that link, very useful.  He suggests that gathering statistics will result in the plan being flushed sometime later.  In that case I'll leave this until tomorrow and check it then as that seem safer than installing new packages and setting events, etc.